# Retaining order in ANTLR4 grammars

Tags: c++, parsing, antlr, antlr4

For the ANTLR4 grammar (just an MWE)

```
grammar T;

sequence: ( a | b )*;

a: FORWARD;
b: RIGHT;

FORWARD: 'f';
RIGHT: 'r';
```

the ANTLR4 C++ backend generates the parser `TParser` deriving from `antlr4::Parser`. I am interested in the class `TParser::SequenceContext`, derived from `antlr4::ParserRuleContext`:

```
class  SequenceContext : public antlr4::ParserRuleContext {
public:
    SequenceContext(antlr4::ParserRuleContext *parent, size_t invokingState);
    virtual size_t getRuleIndex() const override;
    antlr4::tree::TerminalNode *EOF();
    std::vector<AContext *> a();
    AContext* a(size_t i);
    std::vector<BContext *> b();
    BContext* b(size_t i);

    virtual void enterRule(antlr4::tree::ParseTreeListener *listener) override;
    virtual void exitRule(antlr4::tree::ParseTreeListener *listener) override;

    virtual antlrcpp::Any accept(antlr4::tree::ParseTreeVisitor *visitor) override;
};
```

My problem is that the *order* of the occurrences of `a` and `b` gets lost when I use only the `std::vector<>`s returned by the `SequenceContext::a()` and `SequenceContext::b()` member functions. What is the *best practice* in ANTLR4 grammar formulation to retain the order? Or is there another way to get the order from the parse tree? Note that I don't want to use the visitor or listener interfaces extensively, but rather walk through the parse tree myself.

A similar example would be a grammar like (only relevant parts shown):

```
grammar U;

for_statement: 'for' '(' expr? ';' expr? ';' expr? ')' statement
```

The context for the rule would present only a list of expressions to the user. If only the last expression is given, the context gives us only a vector of `expr` with a size of 1 and without an easy why to determine whether the first, second or third expression was given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the primary example using the following modifications to the grammar:

```
grammar T;

sequence: direction*;

direction: a | b;

a: FORWARD;
b: RIGHT;

FORWARD: 'f';
RIGHT: 'r';
```

which gives a vector of `direction` rule contexts in the `sequence` context. In the `direction` rule context, either `a` or `b` is set (`a() != nullptr` or `b() != nullptr`).

For the latter example, the grammar can be modified using a special function of the ANTLR grammar that allows us to name the different `expr` parts:

```
grammar U;

for_statement: 'for' '(' first_expr=expr? ';' second_expr=expr? ';' third_expr=expr? ')' statement
```

The `for_statement` context then has `first_expr() != nullptr` if the first expression was given. `first_expr()` returns a pointer to type `UParser::First_exprContext` and provides a normal `expr` context. There are a couple of such helpful functions in the ANTLR4 grammar that can make walking the parse tree more robust in terms of only having to change small parts in the code that uses the parse tree when the grammar changes.

Answer (score 0):

Once you determined that your input is syntactically correct (by parsing it) you can simply use your token stream to walk over all incoming tokens. They are in the exact order as given originally. Use `CommonTokenStream::getTokens()` for the list.